# Debugging Xamarin.iOS crashing app with error: * Assertion condition `!tls' not met

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Ι get intermittent crashes with  **xamarin iOS app** while debugging on physical device with the following error

```
error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/5909/60a17f1c/source/xamarin- macios/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:3901, condition `!tls' not met
```

i am using

```
Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 for Mac
Version 7.6.11 (build 9)
Runtime:Mono 5.16.0.221 (2018-06/b63e5378e38) (64-bit)
Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 9.2
Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.6.99.33
```

Comment: Hi, what's the iOS version of physical device used to test? You'd better use visual studio 2019 to check whether it works. Some features in visual studio 2017 will not support in the latest version of iOS.

Comment: i am using device with ios 13.7

Comment: Okey, do you have iOS 14 device to check this?